# After summer'19 upgrade in APAC (AP8, AP7, AP15) i am unable to get to LWC record pages

Tags: lightning-web-components, summer19

I had a number of LWC pages (both app and record pages) that were working fine until our upgrade this weekend. This morning, we can't open none of our RECORD pages only.

I tried creating a completely new record page and it fails with the same error.

The org is developing a managed package, so everything has a namespace.

The UI fails to get info about the flexipage:

```
POST /aura?r=4&aura.DynamicComponent.getTemplateDescriptorWithExpansion=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: myinstance.lightning.force.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1507
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://myinstance.lightning.force.com
X-SFDC-Request-Id: <Some id here>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: https://myinstance.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/my_prefix__My_Object__c/a0FFF0000FFFEFFFFF/view
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: <Session info here>

message%3D%7B%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22394%3Ba%22%2C%22descriptor%22%3A%22aura%3A%2F%2FDynamicComponentController%2FACTION%24getTemplateDescriptorWithExpansion%22%2C%22callingDescriptor%22%3A%22UNKNOWN%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Flexipage%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%22pageDeveloperName%22%3A%22my_prefix__Myg_Page2%22%2C%22objectApiName%22%3A%22my_prefix__My_Object__c%22%2C%22recordId%22%3A%22a0FFF0000FFFEFFFFF%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%26aura.context%3D%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22SOMEIDHERE%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22TAG%20HERE%22%7D%2C%22dn%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22globals%22%3A%7B%22density%22%3A%22VIEW_ONE%22%2C%22appContextId%22%3A%22SOME%20ID%22%7D%2C%22uad%22%3Atrue%7D%26aura.pageURI%3D%2Flightning%2Fr%2Fmy_prefix__My_Object__c%2Fa0FFF0000FFFEFFFFFAV%2Fview%26aura.token%3DtokenHERE
```

And the actions part of the response comes back as:

```
"actions":[
    {
      "id":"394;a",
      "state":"ERROR",
      "returnValue":null,
      "error":[
        {
          "message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 947460758-10373 (-1122514613)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

With error id being different for different users.

**Update**

Working with SF support I was able to isolate this issue, although there is no solution :(

It seems to only affect orgs that are developing managed packages.
What happens is if you have one **custom** component import another **custom** component, the js can't compile as it can't find the module (for whatever reason now?)

To replicate this, do the following in Summer 19:

1) Create the first component (e.g. here called TestCo)

Html

```
<template>
Hello world!
</template>
```

Js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TestCo extends LightningElement {}
```

Metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="testCo">
<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

2) Create the second component (here called DummyEditor)

Html

```
<template>
<c-test-co></c-test-co>
</template>
```

Js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { TestCo } from 'c/testCo'; // note: this doesn't make any difference

export default class DummyEditor extends LightningElement { }
```

Metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="dummyEditor">
<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<masterLabel>DUMMY</masterLabel>
<targets>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

3) Now add the second component anywhere to a LWC record page

4) Try to open the record (note: it WILL work in App Builder, but not in the console)

**Update 2**

Trying to repro this in a brand new dev org I first added this component to `Account` object - THAT worked. However, when i created a `Custom` object, and added the component to that - it fails the same way.

**Update 3**

As per an answer i got on SF Dev forums, there is a workaround - rename the `TestCo` component to be `Testco`, so the tag is `c-testco`.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000laNKQAY

This is annoying but maybe a way forward while SF are fixing things

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. Having the same issue on all scratch orgs since at least yesterday. Interestingly our components work fine in the app builder too.

Comment: I have the same issue. My scratch Org seems to have been upgraded to Summer 19 over the weekend. However, I have discovered a workaround (well it works for me). I have a LightningOut/VisualForce page with my components on and it doesn't seem to exhibit the problem. If I open the VisualForce page my components get compiled and I can then use the record page.

Comment: @Jon that's a good workaround. Sadly, we don't have anything in VisualForce, we're a brand new dev org working on an ISV package, so it was all a clean-slate LWC, not even Aura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug which has been resolved by 1st July 2019 with the rollout of one of the Summer 19 patches.